# Wrong use of memory?

Tags: esp32, variables, memory

Probably I'm doing something wrong.
I'm writing an Arduino sketch for ESP32.
Among the others I have this function:

```
#define HDR_MAX_LENGHT 4
#define CMD_MAX_LENGHT 5
#define ARG_MAX_LENGHT 5
#define ARG_MAX_NUMBER 8

void ProcessLine(HardwareSerial *serial, char *line)
{
  int ret;
  int argc;
  char header[HDR_MAX_LENGHT + 1];
  char cmd[CMD_MAX_LENGHT + 1];
  char argv[ARG_MAX_NUMBER][ARG_MAX_LENGHT + 1];

  return; // for debugging
}
```

Usage example:

```
void loop() 
{
    static char inBuf[64];

    if (Serial.available())
    {
      size_t size = Serial.readBytes(inBuf, 64);
      inBuf[size] = '\0';
      ProcessLine(&Serial, inBuf);
    }  
}
```

In the last days all worked fine.
After adding other code, I noticed that sometimes my program "hangs": nothing runs. Perhaps it goes in an exception trap.

Commenting out the different sections of the code, I discovered that if I remove the declarations of the variables in `ProcessLine()` no more hangs happen.
The current RAM consumption is negligible: 0.5%.

During the tests NO serial data was received! So the function `ProcessLine()` was *never* called.
Hence, only the declaration of the variables lead to the "hang".

I wonder if there are some mistakes in the code above.
Otherwise, how I can further debug my code to understand what I've done wrong?

Comment: if size is 64 then you write \0 out of the array

Comment: @Juraj good catch, thanks. But as said I'm not sending any data right now.

Comment: Can you write a testable, minimal example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @EdgarBonet unfortunately not because with a minimal example all works as expected (as said, in the beginning of the development there were no issues). For this reason I'm asking how to debug in addition to commenting out some part of the code.

Comment: This is just a guess, but what about compiler optimization? Try to turn optimization off and test again.

Comment: Modify `optimize_level ` in \hardware\arduino\avr\platform.txt. Acceptable values are  `-O0 `,  `-O1 `,  `-O2 `,  `-O3 `,  `-Os ` and  `-Ofast `. Default is  `-Os `.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with these declarations. The fact that the program works when you comment out some lines of code does **not** mean that these lines are causing the problem. It looks like you may have triggered [undefined behavior](https://www.nayuki.io/page/undefined-behavior-in-c-and-cplusplus-programs) somewhere. When this happens, the behavior of the program becomes unpredictable, and can depend on changes to parts of the code that are completely unrelated to the actual problem. A typical example is memory corruption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in a comment, there is nothing wrong with these declarations.
Now, here are some debugging strategies you may try:

1. You can rebuild your program with all compiler warnings enabled. Look
   carefully at the compiler messages and investigate any warning you
   see.
2. You can continue with your current strategy: put back those
   declarations, then try to remove something else. You may find that
   there are multiple pieces of code that, when removed, make your
   program work again. Chances are the problem resides in one of those
   pieces. But then, it may be that the problem is in the interaction
   between multiple pieces rather than in one specific piece.
3. You may just read the code carefully and see if you spot something
   suspicious. This can work sometimes: see how @Juraj spotted a buffer
   overflow in your code snippet just by reading it.
4. You can add debug messages across your program, to check what
   branches are executed, the values of variables...
5. I don't know the ESP32 dev environment, but you can check whether the
   compiler supports adding “sanitizers”. These are pieces of code added
   by the compiler that do run-time checks on your program, and report
   problems as they happen. You may want to enable at least an address
   sanitizer and an undefined behavior sanitizer.
6. If the environment supports it, you can try to run the program in a
   debugger. No success guaranteed: if the program corrupts its memory,
   it may crash in some place unrelated to the actual problem. The
   debugger will tell you where it crashed, which may not be very
   helpful in this case.
7. If the ESP dev environment supports neither 5 nor 6, you may try to
   run your program on your PC. There are a couple of Arduino-compatible
   cores that you can download for running on a PC.